# JOINT MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, ambiguity

If i have tables such as:

```
table_1: 1, 'Hello My Name is Hal', '2009:11:02 08:42'
table_1: 2, 'Hello My Name is Dave', '2009:11:02 08:30'
table_2: 1, 'Ima all #red due to twitter', '2009:11:02 09:42'
```

And lets imagine all the table columns have the same `col_names`

Is there any way i can do a query to return the results in one SELECT on different Rows

Something Along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2 ORDER BY dateReg DESC
```

So my Return will look like:

```
1, 'Ima all #red due to twitter', '2009:11:02 09:42'
1, 'Hello My Name is Hal', '2009:11:02 08:42'
2, 'Hello My Name is Dave', '2009:11:02 08:30'
```

When I try to run the above query I get Ambiguity Errors (Obviously...Duhh..:D) but is there a way we can do that in query rather than sorting in code using PHP.

Any Ideas? Thanks in advance

Comment: it's actually called a JOIN, a 'joint' is something different :)

Comment: I know what a JOIN does, therefore i had to name it different as i coudnt think of any thing else to call it, Turns out its a Union :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`) to combine results from multiple queries:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM table_2
```

(Simple `UNION` will remove duplicates, `UNION ALL` will return *all* results.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use UNION Queries

Answer (score 0):

Use table aliasas ;)

Something like:

`SELECT table1.id AS table1_id, table2.id AS table2_id, table3.id AS table3_id FROM table1, table2, table3`

Comment: This is a cross-join, which is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Using the initial example as a base, is there a way where table2 can overload the row with the same id in table1?

So the expected result would be:

```
1, 'Ima all #red due to twitter', '2009:11:02 09:42'
2, 'Hello My Name is Dave', '2009:11:02 08:30'
```

Comment: One possible solution is to use sub-selects - SELECT * FROM ( (SELECT * FROM table_1) UNION (SELECT * FROM table_2) ) AS `result` GROUP BY `result`.`id`